# Set background colour to Input box in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I'm trying to change the colour entire input of `sap.m.Input`.
Since it is having place holder & inner only border colour is changing.

```
document.getElementById("loginuser-placeholder").style.backgroundColor = "#232055 !important";
document.getElementById("loginuser-inner").style.backgroundColor = "#232055 !important";
```

This is how I tried forcing the elements to change its colour.

I also tried this:

```
var loginuser = new sap.m.Input("loginuser",{placeholder:"Username"});
loginuser.addStyleClass(".loginuser{background-color:#232055 !important }");
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTzb.jpg

Comment: #loginuser-placeholder {background:#232044 !important;} in your css doesn't work?

Comment: I tested this on a div, p, a, span and h1 tags and your top javascript works fine...

Comment: value state does not help? e.g. on the Input Field in event LiveChange: liveChange : function(oEvent) { this.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error); },

Answer (score 0):

When setting multiple values with JavaScript, it is not possible to do it in one, you need to call document.getElementById multiple times, like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "!important"
}
```

not

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "blue !important"
}
```

Comment: #loginuser{background-color: #232055 }
 #loginuser-placeholder {background:#232044 } 
Solved my problem,,Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a class, all you need to do is

> `oInput.addStyleClass("loginInput")`

and in your css file you will add the style

> `.sapMInput.loginInput {
>      color: blue;
>   }`

Comment: It seems, You need to omit .sapMInput, pass background-color AND specify the hex-code of "blue" along with !important...